# Install SonarQube Coverity Plugin

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, coverity

I'm trying to install the [coverity plugin for sonarqube](https://github.com/coverity/coverity-sonar-plugin) and followed all the instructions and executed the mvn command.
the build is successful. however, the widget does not show up after restarting sonarqube.
is there anything I missed? any help is appreciated.

Comment: which mvn command do you used and the widget are be activated in the dashboard and wich coverage mvn plugin do you use for the lcov ?

Comment: I used this command: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=xmldsig-1.0.jar -DgroupId=javax.xml.crypto -DartifactId=xmldsig -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DcreateChecksum=true`

I expected to get a .jar file to put it into the extensions folder of sonarqube, but the build succeeded without. I must admit I'm not very familiar with java technology

Comment: how do you scan your project with sonarqube by jenkins or maven plugin or sonarqube runner ... ? and wich command do you use ?

Comment: Maybe you can find some relevant error-lines in the SonarQube logging file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after contakting coverity specialists, it turned out to be a compatibility problem. the coverity plugin for sonarqube works exclusively for sonarcube 5.3 (and not with version 6.1 I used). although the widget eventually showed up, the plugin was not able to get the defects from coverity and probably won't be able to do so at the moment for other versions than sonarqube 5.3.